# Javascript Quiz to calculate total options selected

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to make a quiz like this:
For each question there are different numbers of answer options and each option will have a different value. At the end of the quiz I need to get a total of the selected options. I am not able to get it run. Any suggestions?

The HTML looks like:

```html
<div id="question" class="question"></div>
<label class="option">
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="" />
  <span class="option"></span>
</label>
```

```js
const questions = [
  {
    question: 'Q1',
    answers: [
      { text: 'A1', score: 100 },
      { text: 'A2', score: 60 },
      { text: 'A3', score: 30 }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'Q2',
    answers: [
      { text: 'A1', score: 150 },
      { text: 'A2', score: 130 },
      { text: 'A3', score: 250 },
      { text: 'A4', score: 250 },
      { text: 'A5', score: 250 }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'Q3',
    answers: [
      { text: 'A1', score: 250 },
      { text: 'A2', score: 500 }
    ]
  } 
]
```

Comment: where's the javascript in which u r facing issues?

Comment: Have you tried to put all the answer into a select box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, I put all the answers of each question into a select box.

```js
const questions = [
  {
    question: 'Q1',
    answers: [
      { text: 'A1', score: 100 },
      { text: 'A2', score: 60 },
      { text: 'A3', score: 30 }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'Q2',
    answers: [
      { text: 'A1', score: 150 },
      { text: 'A2', score: 130 },
      { text: 'A3', score: 250 },
      { text: 'A4', score: 250 },
      { text: 'A5', score: 250 }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'Q3',
    answers: [
      { text: 'A1', score: 250 },
      { text: 'A2', score: 500 }
    ]
  } 
]
let questionZone=document.getElementById('questionZone');
questionZone.innerHTML='';
questions.forEach(item=>{
    let div=document.createElement('div');
  div.className="question";
  div.id=item.question;
  div.innerHTML=item.question+':';
  questionZone.appendChild(div);
  let label=document.createElement('label');
  let select=document.createElement('select');
  label.className="option";
  label.appendChild(select);
  select.name=item.question;
  item.answers.forEach(answerItem=>{
    let option=document.createElement('option');
    option.text=answerItem.text;
    option.value=answerItem.score;
    select.appendChild(option)
  })
    div.appendChild(label);
})

function getTotalScore(vv){
    let totalValue=0;
    questions.forEach(item=>{
    totalValue+=Number(vv[item.question].value);
  });
  let totalScore=document.getElementById("totalScore");
  totalScore.innerHTML='Total Score:'+totalValue;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form id='form1' onsubmit="return false;">
<div id='questionZone'>
</div>
<button onclick='getTotalScore(this.form)'>
  Get Total Score
</button>
</form>
<div id="totalScore">
Total Score:0
</div>
```